# Asp.net updatepanel clears checkboxlist selections

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, checkboxlist

I have an ASP.Net CheckBoxList control inside an Ajax UpdatePanel.

I will include the code (C#) along with the HTML below.

I have found that it is something with the CheckBoxList not persisting through the post back.

BTW, it is a little messy.  It is a prototype.

This is the method used to populate the original CheckBoxList

```
protected void BindCheckboxes()
{
    chkBuildings.Items.Clear();
    chkNeighborhoods.Items.Clear();
    string city = ddlFindHome_Location.SelectedItem.Value.ToLower();
    ResidentDataContext rdc = new ResidentDataContext(Utility.Lookup.GetResidentConnectionString());
    var neighs = (from n in rdc.spNeighborhoods where n.vchCity.Equals(city) select n);
    foreach (var neighborhood in neighs)
    {
        ListItem li = new ListItem();
        li.Value = neighborhood.intNeighborhoodID.ToString();
        li.Attributes["onclick"] = string.Format("document.getElementById('{0}').click();", btnNeighHack.ClientID);
        li.Text = neighborhood.vchNeighborhood;
        chkNeighborhoods.Items.Add(li);
    }
    var builds = (from b in rdc.spBuildings
                  join nb in rdc.spNeighborhoodBuildings on b.intBuildingID equals nb.intBuildingID
                  join n in rdc.spNeighborhoods on nb.intNeightborhoodID equals n.intNeighborhoodID
                  where n.vchCity.ToLower().Equals(city)
                  select b).Distinct();
    foreach (var buildings in builds)
    {
        ListItem li = new ListItem();
        li.Value = buildings.intBuildingID.ToString();
        li.Text = buildings.vchName;
        chkBuildings.Items.Add(li);
    }
    upNeighs.Update();
    upBuilds.Update();
}
```

BindCheckboxes() is called from:

```
protected void ddlFindHome_Location_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindCheckboxes();
}
```

This is the post back method for populating the Check Boxes of another CheckBoxList

```
protected void btnNeighHack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<int> neighs = new List<int>();

    foreach (ListItem li in chkNeighborhoods.Items)
    {
        if (li.Selected)
            neighs.Add(Convert.ToInt32(li.Value));
    }
    ResidentDataContext rdc = new ResidentDataContext(Utility.Lookup.GetResidentConnectionString());
    var builds = (from b in rdc.spBuildings
                  join nb in rdc.spNeighborhoodBuildings on b.intBuildingID equals nb.intBuildingID
                  where neighs.Contains(nb.intNeightborhoodID)
                  select b.intBuildingID).Distinct();
    foreach (ListItem li in chkBuildings.Items)
    {
        li.Selected = false;
    }
    foreach (ListItem li in chkBuildings.Items)
    {
        if (builds.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(li.Value)))
            li.Selected = true;
    }
    upBuilds.Update();
}
```

Here is the ASP.Net HTML

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upNeighs" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div style="font-weight: bold;">
            Neighborhood
        </div>
        <div style="padding-top: 7px; padding-left: 3px;">
            <input type="checkbox" id="chkNeighborhood_CheckAll" />Select All
        </div>
        <hr />
        <div>
            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkNeighborhoods" runat="server" />
            <asp:Button style="display: none;" ID="btnNeighHack" runat="server" 
                onclick="btnNeighHack_Click" />
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upBuilds" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div style="padding-left: 6px; padding-top: 5px; font-weight: bold;">
            Building
        </div>
        <div>
            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkBuildings" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

---

I should have mentioned that the bindcheckboxes() function is called from

```
protected void ddlFindHome_Location_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindCheckboxes();
}
```

So it is always a PostBack.  But I think you might be onto something with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research, I have found that the controls aren't persisting through the post back, and are dropping out of the view state.  So each time it posts back, there is a null object returned from:

```
protected Control PostBackControl
{
    get { return Page.FindControl(Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET")); }
}
```

but it sees that the drop down list's value isn't the default value and starts to rebind everything.

When I only bind the checkbox lists when the PostBackControl is the drop down list, the controls never get bound since everything in the update panel is dropping out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

```
    protected void BindCheckboxes()
    {
        if(!IsPostBack)
{
chkBuildings.Items.Clear();
        chkNeighborhoods.Items.Clear();
        string city = ddlFindHome_Location.SelectedItem.Value.ToLower();
        ResidentDataContext rdc = new ResidentDataContext(Utility.Lookup.GetResidentConnectionString());
        var neighs = (from n in rdc.spNeighborhoods where n.vchCity.Equals(city) select n);
        foreach (var neighborhood in neighs)
        {
            ListItem li = new ListItem();
            li.Value = neighborhood.intNeighborhoodID.ToString();
            li.Attributes["onclick"] = string.Format("document.getElementById('{0}').click();", btnNeighHack.ClientID);
            li.Text = neighborhood.vchNeighborhood;
            chkNeighborhoods.Items.Add(li);
        }
        var builds = (from b in rdc.spBuildings
                      join nb in rdc.spNeighborhoodBuildings on b.intBuildingID equals nb.intBuildingID
                      join n in rdc.spNeighborhoods on nb.intNeightborhoodID equals n.intNeighborhoodID
                      where n.vchCity.ToLower().Equals(city)
                      select b).Distinct();
        foreach (var buildings in builds)
        {
            ListItem li = new ListItem();
            li.Value = buildings.intBuildingID.ToString();
            li.Text = buildings.vchName;
            chkBuildings.Items.Add(li);
        }
        upNeighs.Update();
        upBuilds.Update();
}
    }
```

try that.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you clear your CheckBoxList everytime you change a selection, it's gonna clear your selected items too. I would load the items at page_load instead.